# What is the purpose of declarative_base()

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

[image]

I've been reading through the docs (screenshot) as well as some online questions about  declarative_base(). eg https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/sqlalchemy/-Zl9T7Q7awY as I try to understand its usage in projects like https://github.com/hack4impact/flask-base/tree/master/app

This project uses flask-sqlalchemy (http://flask-sqlalchemy.pocoo.org/2.1/quickstart/)

From researching I see its possible to create sqlalchemy table models that look like:

```
class Property(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'properties'
    __searchable__ = ['body']
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    title = db.Column(db.String(140))
    body = db.Column(db.String(1400))
    img = db.Column(db.String(140))
```

or that inherit from base, eg.

```
Base = declarative_base()
class Property(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'properties'
    __searchable__ = ['body']
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    title = db.Column(db.String(140))
    body = db.Column(db.String(1400))
    img = db.Column(db.String(140))
```

Why should I use Base here?

PS:

in the project above the `app/_init.py` initializes the flask app with multiple extensions including sqlalchemy:

```
mail = Mail()
db = SQLAlchemy()
.....

def create_app(config_name):
    ....
    db.init_app(app)
    login_manager.init_app(app)
    ...
```

db is then imported into the model files.

Comment: What’s `db`? If you’re using flask-sqlalchemy, `db.Model` was probably created exactly like that, with SQLAlchemy’s `declarative_base`.

Comment: I've added more info to the question. In the project above declarative_base is not used at the time of app creation.please see https://github.com/hack4impact/flask-base/blob/master/app/__init__.py

Comment: What’s `SQLAlchemy` in `db = SQLAlchemy()`? I don’t think SQLAlchemy itself has a type named that…

Comment: I'm using flask-sqlalchemy, http://flask-sqlalchemy.pocoo.org/2.1/quickstart/

Comment: Okay, so there you go. If you were just using SQLAlchemy by itself, you would inherit from a base you created with `declarative_base`. flask-sqlalchemy does that for you, though, and calls it `db.Model`.

Comment: Thanks for looking at this. I'm still trying to wrap my head around the pieces of sql-alchemy, but what exactly is base? I can see that the tables inherit from it, but what functionality does it add?

Comment: Have you read http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/tutorial.html#declare-a-mapping